# Z-index is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Why #opacwall covers #moviechoose ?

```
<div id="moviechoose" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;background: #f2c249;border: none;position:absolute;left:50px;top:50px;z-index:1;border-radius:130px; display: none;"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('.circlemenubutton').click(function(){

    $('#moviechoose').show(200);
    $('<div/>', {
        'id':'opacwall',
        'style':' width: 100%;height: 100%;background: black;border: none;position:fixed;left:0%;top:0%;z-index:0;opacity:0.6'

    }).appendTo('body');
    });
```

Comment: Is creating a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) possible?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/39fofp3c/

Comment: IE7- expirienses some z-index issues, have no idea what's the browser you test with.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo of what I think you're trying to do https://jsfiddle.net/mzg1v0q5/ using jQuery-2.1.3

People often get confused with z-index, so I would recommend reading this article to fully understand it:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

The key piece of information (in my opinion) is because `z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative`.  You have done this in your example code, so hopefully looking at the fiddle posted will help you out.